# How to prevent jumping of the content on changing elements position from relative to fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wondering how can I prevent jumping and make a smooth transition of the content where I have one element that changes it's position from relative to fixed. I have made a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8q6rbzj7/29/). I have created 3 elements:

```
<div id="top-bar">
  <p>
    Top bar
  </p>
</div>
<div id="header">
  <p>
    Header
  </p>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
</div>
```

I have tried with adding `margin-top` of the `height` of the `top-bar`, when `top-bar` disappears and  the `header` gets position `fixed` to the `content` element, but that didn't help. How can I make this smooth without jumping of the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make the value of `margin-top` the same value as the `height` of the **header** (100px) and not the **top bar**, as you have to add what you removed.

```js
const header = document.querySelector('#header');
const content = document.querySelector('#content');
const rect = header.getBoundingClientRect();
const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
const headerTop = rect.top + scrollTop;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.scrollY > headerTop) {
    header.classList.add('fixed');
    content.classList.add('margin-top');
  } else {
    header.classList.remove('fixed');
    content.classList.remove('margin-top');
  }
});
```

```css
body,html {
margin:0;
}

#top-bar {
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  height: 900px;
  background: blue;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed!important;
}

.margin-top {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

#top-bar p,#header p {
margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top-bar">
  <p>
    Top bar
  </p>
</div>
<div id="header">
  <p>
    Header
  </p>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That is why I added 40px, the height of the top bar, because that is what I thought is being lost when I scrolled to the header, how come it is 100px, if you could explain me that?

Comment: @Leff 100px is the height of the header that you make fixed .. when you make it fixed you remove its height from the normal flow, so you have to add it again ;)

Comment: ah, of course, I forgot about that, thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your solution was because your margin-top class had 40px margin and your header is 100px high. You could also change the margin to match the header height as well.

see https://jsfiddle.net/8q6rbzj7/35/

```
.margin-top {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Best to go with the simplest approach, just wrap header with a wrapper with the same height as header.

https://jsfiddle.net/8q6rbzj7/33/

```
<div class="header-container">
  <div id="header">
    <p>
      Header
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header-container {
  height: 100px;
}
```

JS was reduced because you don't need that margin top thing

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.scrollY > headerTop) {
    header.classList.add('fixed');

  } else {
    header.classList.remove('fixed');

  }
});
```